# How create task for lead object through process builder

Tags: process-builder, leads

I have a doubt in create task for lead object through process builder. I don't know what is wrong here. Anyone please help me.

This is my entry criteria.
[image]

this is my create record action.[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What you put the criteria for the Object Level? While "Creating a record" or While "Creating and Updating a Record"?

Comment: Creating record

Comment: which ID did you gave for the Assigned To ID field?

Comment: User id Who are available in users

Answer (score 2):

To relate a task to a lead you have to use the WhoId (more info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm ).

In the process builder you have to map the field "Name ID" not the "Related To ID".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put any Value for the 'Related ID' Field because it is non-editable field

If possible, try to delete that field from the Creating a Record in Process Builder

then the process will flow normally

**Update:**
For verification, you can goto any Lead and If you try to create any Task, There you can find the Uneditable field of "Related To"

Comment: Then how can I assign a task with lead?

Comment: @Jana Shree, Actually this is a one of the case for salesforce. You can create the "Task" From "Lead" by a Trigger or Workflow or Process Builder or Flow. But whatever you takes, the thing is the "Related To" Field is uneditable to the user for the Lead Object itself... So I will suggest you to try with the some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Field "Due Date Only" and you should probably set it to TODAY()

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to kick it off in Process Builder and then call Flow to create the Task. You will be able bring all the data to build out the task. Per the docs you should be able to relate to a Lead, however you will need to use Name. [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_fields.htm&type=5)